# FORTRAN: dummy argument

Tags: fortran, warnings, fortran90

I am try to use the RK-4th order explicit method to solve the (planar) 3-body problem. I have a set of 4*N first order ODE where N is the number of the objects. 4 is because for each object I have the position vector equal to {x,y} and the velocity vector equal to {vx,vy}.

Unfortunately the program do not work properly, it give to me a warning in the derivative subroutine that I can not be able to understand:

```
A dummy argument with an explicit INTENT(OUT) declaration is not given an explicit value
```

I tried to remove all the INTENT declaration from the subroutine to try to solve the problem in the code. After that no warning appear, but still, the program continue to work wrongly. 
Here is the code:

```
MODULE constant
!----------------------------
!   Initial Condition
!----------------------------
REAL*8, PARAMETER :: m0 = 1.9891e30 ! mass sun (kg)
REAL*8, PARAMETER :: m1 = 5.9736e24 ! mass earth (kg)
REAL*8, PARAMETER :: m2 = 1e20 ! mass of test particle (kg)
REAL*8, PARAMETER :: G = 6.6738e-11 ! G (Nm**2/kg**2)

END MODULE constant


    PROGRAM bodies_rk
    use constant
    implicit none
    integer :: n_step,n_periods,k_max,k
    real*8 :: ome,dt,duepi,m_per,t_per
    real*8 :: x0,y0,z0,vx0,vy0,vz0
    real*8 :: x1,y1,z1,vx1,vy1,vz1
    real*8 :: x2,y2,z2,vx2,vy2,vz2
    real*8 :: a_step,h,t,phi,covx,covy,covz,comx,comy,comz
    real*8 :: r0,r1,r2
    real*8, DIMENSION(12):: x

!--------------------------------
!       Test run for Runge-Kutta
!--------------------------------
duepi=8.d0*DATAN(1.d0)
ome=1.d0
t_per=duepi/ome
n_step=1000                    ! step per period
n_periods=5000                 ! periods

!! position of the Sun !! (in m)
x0 = 0.d0 ; y0 = 0.d0 ; z0 = 0.d0
!! position of the Earth !! 
x1 = 1.496e11 ; y1 = 0.d0 ; z1 = 0.d0 !
!! position of the test-particle !! 
x2 = 3e12 ; y2 = 0.d0 ; z2 = 0.d0 

r0 = sqrt(x0**2.d0+y0**2.d0+z0**2.d0)
r1 = sqrt(x1**2.d0+y1**2.d0+z1**2.d0)
r2 = sqrt(x2**2.d0+y2**2.d0+z2**2.d0)

!! velocity of the Sun !! (in m/s)
vx0 =  0.d0 ; vy0 =  0.d0; vz0 = 0.d0
!! velocity of the Earth !! 
vx1 = 0.d0; vy1 =  29.8e3 ; vz1 = 0.d0 !  
!! velocity of the test-particle !! 
vx2 = 0.d0; vy2 =  sqrt((G*(m0+m1+m2))/r2) ; vz2 = 0.d0 !  


!! time step size and number of time step !!
a_step=dfloat(n_step)
dt=t_per/a_step
k_max=n_periods*n_step

!! move to center of Mass and velocity !!
comx =  (m0*x0+m1*x1+m2*x2)/(m0+m1+m2)
comy =  (m0*y0+m1*y1+m2*y2)/(m0+m1+m2)
comz =  (m0*z0+m1*z1+m2*z2)/(m0+m1+m2)

covx =  (m0*vx0+m1*vx1+m2*vx2)/(m0+m1+m2)
covy =  (m0*vy0+m1*vy1+m2*vy2)/(m0+m1+m2)
covz =  (m0*vz0+m1*vz1+m2*vz2)/(m0+m1+m2)

x0 = x0 - comx ; x1 = x1 - comx ; x2 = x2 - comx
y0 = y0 - comy ; y1 = y1 - comy ; y2 = y2 - comy
z0 = z0 - comz ; z1 = z1 - comz ; y2 = y2 - comy

vx0 = vx0 - covx ; vx1 = vx1 - covx ; vx2 = vx2 - covx
vy0 = vy0 - covy ; vy1 = vy1 - covy ; vx2 = vx2 - covx 
vz0 = vz0 - covz ; vz1 = vz1 - covz ; vx2 = vx2 - covx


!! declare the vector of position for the objects !! 
x(1)=x0
x(2)=vx0
x(3)=y0
x(4)=vy0

x(5)=x1
x(6)=vx1
x(7)=y1
x(8)=vy1

x(9)=x2
x(10)=vx2
x(11)=y2
x(12)=vy2

t=0.d0

DO k=1,k_max    ! -------------------------->
  CALL kutta(x,t,dt)
  IF(MOD(k,n_step) == 0) THEN
    WRITE(23,*) x(5),x(7) ! test print: orbit of the Earth
  END IF 
END DO  !  <---------------------


END PROGRAM bodies_rk

SUBROUTINE kutta(x,t,dt)
implicit none
REAL*8, INTENT(OUT)                        :: x(12)
REAL*8, INTENT(IN OUT)                     :: t
!----------------------------------------------------------
!     Subroutine  Runge-Kutta 4th Explicit
!----------------------------------------------------------
REAL*8 :: k1(12), k2(12), k3(12), k4(12)
real*8 :: told,dt,h
integer :: j
REAL*8, DIMENSION(12) ::f

told=t
call phi(t,x(1),x(2),x(3),x(4),     &
&          x(5),x(6),x(7),x(8),     &
&          x(9),x(10),x(11),x(12),  &
&          f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),     &
&          f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),     &
&          f(9),f(10),f(11),f(12))

DO j=1,12
  k1(j)=f(j)
END DO

h=0.5d0*dt
call phi(t+h,x(1)+h*k1(1),x(2)+h*k1(2),x(3)+h*k1(3),x(4)+h*k1(4),  & 
&            x(5)+h*k1(5),x(6)+h*k1(6),x(7)+h*k1(7),x(8)+h*k1(8),  & 
&            x(9)+h*k1(9),x(10)+h*k1(10),x(11)+h*k1(11),x(12)+h*k1(12),  & 
&            f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),f(9),f(10),f(11),f(12))

DO j=1,12
  k2(j)=f(j)
END DO

call phi(t+h,x(1)+h*k2(1),x(2)+h*k2(2),x(3)+h*k2(3),x(4)+h*k2(4),  & 
&            x(5)+h*k2(5),x(6)+h*k2(6),x(7)+h*k2(7),x(8)+h*k2(8),  & 
&            x(9)+h*k2(9),x(10)+h*k2(10),x(11)+h*k2(11),x(12)+h*k2(12),  & 
&            f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),f(9),f(10),f(11),f(12))

DO j=1,12
  k3(j)=f(j)
END DO

call phi(t+dt,x(1)+dt*k3(1),x(2)+dt*k3(2),x(3)+dt*k3(3),x(4)+dt*k3(4),  &
&             x(5)+dt*k3(5),x(6)+dt*k3(6),x(7)+dt*k3(7),x(8)+dt*k3(8),  &
&             x(9)+dt*k3(9),x(10)+dt*k3(10),x(11)+dt*k3(11),x(12)+dt*k3(12),  &
&             f(1),f(2),f(3),f(4),f(5),f(6),f(7),f(8),f(9),f(10),f(11),f(12))

DO j=1,12
  k4(j)=f(j)
END DO

DO j=1,12
  x(j)=x(j)+(k1(j)+2.d0*k2(j)+2.d0*k3(j)+k4(j))*dt/6.d0
END DO

t=t+dt

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE kutta


subroutine phi(t,x0,vx0,y0,vy0,  &
&                fx0,fvx0,fy0,fvy0,   &
&                x1,vx1,y1,vy1,  &
&                fx1,fvx1,fy1,fvy1,   &
&                x2,vx2,y2,vy2,  &
&                fx2,fvx2,fy2,fvy2)
use constant
implicit none
REAL*8, INTENT(IN OUT)              :: t
REAL*8, INTENT(IN)                  :: x1,x0,x2
REAL*8, INTENT(IN)                  :: vx1,vx0,vx2
REAL*8, INTENT(IN)                  :: y1,y0,y2
REAL*8, INTENT(IN)                  :: vy1,vy0,vy2
REAL*8, INTENT(OUT)                 :: fx1,fx0,fx2
REAL*8, INTENT(OUT)                 :: fvx1,fvx0,fvx2
REAL*8, INTENT(OUT)                 :: fy1,fy0,fy2
REAL*8, INTENT(OUT)                 :: fvy1,fvy0,fvy2
real*8 :: r0,r1,r2
!----------
!       Define the components of the derivative of the vectorial field to solve:
!      dx/dt=fx(t,x,vx,y,vy)  dvx/dt=fvx(t,x,vx,y,vy)
!      dy/dt=fy(t,x,vx,y,vy)  dvy/dt=fvy(t,x,vx,y,vy)
!----------

r0=SQRT(((x2-x1)**2.d0+(y2-y1)**2.d0)**3.d0)
r1=SQRT(((x0-x2)**2.d0+(y0-y2)**2.d0)**3.d0)
r2=SQRT(((x1-x0)**2.d0+(y1-y0)**2.d0)**3.d0)

fx0=vx0
fy0=vy0
fvx0 = -G*((m1*(x0-x1))/r2**3.d0)-G*((m2*(x0-x2))/r1)
fvy0 = -G*((m1*(y0-y1))/r2**3.d0)-G*((m2*(y0-y2))/r1)

fx1=vx1
fy1=vy1
fvx0 = -G*((m2*(x1-x0))/r0**3.d0)-G*((m0*(x1-x2))/r2)
fvy0 = -G*((m2*(y1-y0))/r0**3.d0)-G*((m0*(y1-y2))/r2)

fx2=vx2
fy2=vy2
fvx2 = -G*((m0*(x2-x0))/r1**3.d0)-G*((m1*(x2-x1))/r0)
fvy2 = -G*((m0*(y2-y0))/r1**3.d0)-G*((m1*(y2-y1))/r0)

RETURN
END subroutine phi
```

In this version of the code I just do not delete the `INTENT` inside the subroutine. Maybe the `INTENT` warning is uncorrelated with the wrong output from the code but at least I can solve one of the problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You are aware of the fact, that by editing the question to reflect my answer you just removed the cause of the warning, right? In the current version, that warning does not appear anymore!

Comment: I correct if because actually you fix it. :D So this post should be closed. I correct it also because everyone can use the program if they want.

Comment: Well, that is not how SO works... Posts are not closed when a correct answer is given! If they were closed, how could others benefit from your question?

Comment: I rolled back the post to the original version...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`fvx1` and `fvy1` are actually never used within the subroutine `phi` - that's what the compiler is complaining about. If your code depends on those values it will certainly produce wrong results.

BTW: `t+h` or `t+dt` are constant expressions (you evaluate two sums), so you can't use it as a dummy argument with intent `out` or `inout`, as is `t` in the subroutine `phi` (although `t` is also never used within that routine).

Comment: Thanks for the observation, yes they should be used in the routine and in fact I corect it. Anyway the problem still persist. 
Actually t+dt (or + h) should be used by the RK-4TH subroutine to increment the time step and then, at each time step, it will compute the phi routine upgrading the velocity and accelerations.

Comment: Well, if `t` does not change during the subroutine `phi`, using the sums is allowed - just change the intent to `in` for `t`.

Comment: Another note: Instead of `**2.d0`/`**3.d0` you should use integer powers `**2`/`**3` s.t. the compiler can optimize these operations.